# How to add a new vnode with Juju 1.20.13 in a environment

Tags: juju

I've installed Juju (1.20.13 via ppa stable) and MaaS (1.7 via ppa stable) on the same virtual server (ubuntu 14.04) and created some vnode with kvm e virt-manager.
I've already configured juju to work with MaaS, and all the vnode are in ready status. 
Then I've made the bootstrapping of the environment maas on a vnode (CloudMaaSRCNode0.maas) with Juju using the command

**`$: juju bootstap CloudMaaSRCNode0.maas -e maas`**

everything went well, I also deployed juju-gui on it without receive any problem. 
But when I tried to add a second vnode on the same environment, with the command,

**`$: juju add-machine CloudMaaSRCNode1.maas -e maas`**

the vnode starts the boot but after few second it goes down, juju tries to boot it more time and in its status I received the following error:

**`$: juju status -e maas`**

```
environment: maas
machines:
  "0":
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.13
    dns-name: CloudMaaSRCNode0.maas
    instance-id: /MAAS/api/1.0/nodes/node-399979e4-7ad2-11e4-882f-5254002bc2e6/
    series: trusty
    hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=1024M tags=virtual
    state-server-member-status: has-vote
  "1":
    agent-state-info: 'cannot run instances: gomaasapi: got error back from server:
      409 CONFLICT (No available node matches constraints: name=CloudMaaSRCNode1.maas)'
    instance-id: pending
    series: trusty
services:  }
```

using the following command on MaaS the vnode's name result the same reported on MaaS dashboard

**`virsh -c qemu+ssh://user@x.x.x.x/system list --all`**

```
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 2     CloudMaaSRCMaster              running
 -     CloudMaaSRCNode0.maas          running
 -     CloudMaaSRCNode1.maas shut off
 -     CloudMaaSRCNode2.maas shut off
```

During my last installations of MaaS and Juju with their previously release I've had any errors like that.
I've also try to re-build the same environment using Ubuntu 14.10 but the result has been the same.

I've found this docs about juju

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/clouds-manual

that explains how to add the node to environment but I think nodes have to be started first and then we can install juju agent.

Anyone has the same my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started having all my vnode in ready status, then I made the bootstrapping with juju

**`$: juju bootstap CloudMaaSRCNode0.maas -e maas`**

After that I've started the rest of vnode from MaaS, and at the end of the procedure of ubuntu installer, I've run the following command for each vnode

**`$: juju add-machine ssh:CloudMaaSRCNode1.maas -e maas`**

in this way all vnode have been added on maas environment

Comment: To "reserve" a specific MAAS node for your juju environment, I think the best practice is to use this syntax: juju add-machine <env-name>:<node-hostname>. For example, in your case, it would be "juju add-machine maas:CloudMaaSRCNode1.maas". That being said, the only reason to do this is when you know you will need a specific machine beforehand. Normally you would just juju deploy services and juju would pick a machine from the environment at random, if no constraints were speficied.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that juju couldn't find a machine named CloudMaaSRCNode1.maas in your MAAS server that was in the "Ready" state, that is, ready to be used. Can you check in your MAAS node list that this machine exists, with that name, and that it is available?

Comment: all my vnodes are already in "ready" status. The entire infrastructure has been realized using Ubuntu 14.04Lts. If you right the vnode didn't make the deploy on MaaS

Comment: You didn't say anything about the node name, it also has to match CloudMaaSRCNode1.maas, in the case of your error message from earlier.

Comment: sorry I've just corrected the post, it was my fault to write the post. Anyway, in my lab I've run the correct command. I've tried also to re-create the same environment on a new clear Ubuntu 14.04, but after the upgrade of MaaS and Juju via ppa stable I obtained the same error.